# weird html_entity_decode behaviour for invalid html entities when set in UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, html-encode

how to avoid decoding of entities which shouldn't be touched as if used in UTF-8 mode html_entities_decode returns crazy invalid characters i.e. `&#56868756256;`

so this on will try to convert it and will fail with invalid utf-8 charater
`html_entity_decode('&#56868756256;',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');`

but on the other hand this one `html_entity_decode('&#56868756256;')` won't convert at all, will just return `&#56868756256;` rather than � like the first one.

Comment: ok I have tried utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1'));
 and it works but not for polish characters so not solution